# Exterior light fixture

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture

Exterior light: what do I do with the bare wires after I connect them? Do I connect it to the screw going into the housing on the wall? Or do I just put a wire nut on it the way I did the other two?

[image]

This is the switch that goes to the exterior light (I was asking what I do with the bare wire). After I fix the switch, I still need to know what to do with the bare wire.

[image]

Comment: Can you add some detail and a picture. What color wire? If you are referring to the bare copper wire then typically you would want to connect it to the earth screw on the fixture. If your exterior light / box has any metal you need to ensure it's earthed.

Comment: Well I got one question answered when I took off the cover plate and pulled off these switches real quick the one has a big crack and obviously I’m gonna have to replace it here is a picture

Comment: I brought your pictures over from the other question.

Answer (score 1):

The bare copper wires are your ground wires. They don't need to be connected to the box because it's non metal. The grounds are all crimped together in the box as they should be. Once you replace the broken switch, the ground wire in the box should be attached to the green screw on the switch. At the fixture location, the bare copper ground needs to be attached to the fixture ground wire with a wire nut. If the fixture box is metal, then the ground wire needs to be attached to it. Any bracket needed to mount the fixture should also be connected to the ground.

Comment: Thank you so the two bare wires I will put them together with a wire nut like I’m going to do with the black and black in the white and white as soon as I replace the broken switch. 
I have tried several times to hire a reputable electrician but it seems nobody wants to do small jobs or most people are just not working I guess? So I am attempting to do these little things myself and I so appreciate your help